# Way to disable Flash Player for a particular app

Tags: macos, flash-player

Is there a way to block a particular app from using the Flash player?

For example, in the Reeder app for Mac OS X, Flash slows down the app considerably when loading Flash content like YouTube/Vimeo videos. I want to block Reeder from using the Flash player completely.

I do not want to delete Flash player from my Mac OS X completely because I need it in other apps.

I'm using Mac OS X 10.6.8 and Flash Player 10.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reeder is using webkit to display HTML. If you install the ClickToFlash Safari plugin, this will replace embedded flash with a clickable element for all webkit apps, allowing you to choose whether or not to view: http://clicktoflash.com/.

Answer (score -1):

You have probably heard of [NoScript](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/noscript/).

NoScript is a browser add-on that blocks scripts (flash, java, etc.) from running in websites. By default, it blocks all scripts from all the websites that I visit. If it's a trusted site, then I can configure noscript to allow some of the scripts to run, or all of the scripts from that site to load, then run.

Comment: I believe Reeder is a standalone application (i.e. not in a web browser).

Comment: 1) Like @boehj said, Reeder is a standalone application. 2) I do not want to block certain flash websites inside the app, but disable access to the flash player itself.